# Заменить множество одинаковых if

Tags: php

Есть множество if c примерно одинаковым содержимым, к примеру:

```
if ($status=="0")
    {
        $title="Новая";
    }

if ($status=="1")
    {
        $title="Старая";
    }

if ($status=="2")
    {
        $title="Архивная";
    }
```

Как упростить данную конструкцию? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @astimated, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте такую конструкцию:

```
$titleByStatus = [
    "0" => "Новая",
    "1" => "Старая",
    "2" => "Архивная"
];

$title = $titleByStatus[$status];
```

Если у вас `status` может принимать и другие значения, не из таблицы, воспользуйтесь [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @astimated: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

[switch](http://php.net//manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php)

> Оператор switch подобен серии операторов IF с одинаковым условием. Во многих случаях вам может понадобиться сравнивать одну и ту же переменную (или выражение) с множеством различных значений, и выполнять различные участки кода в зависимости от того, какое значение принимает эта переменная (или выражение). Это именно тот случай, для которого удобен оператор switch.

Answer (score 0):

Тернарно:

```
$title = ($status=="0" ? "Новая" : ($status=="1" ? "Старая" : "Архивная"));
```

Comment: Говорят, в аду есть отдельный котел для программистов которые пишут такие конструкции.

Ещё пару статусов - и дебаг сего превратиться в веселое анальное пути шествие.

Comment: я лишь предложил еще один способ укрощения кода вопроса, помимо свича и массива. и, кстати, такие конструкции сплошь и рядом используются.

Comment: не нужно писать минимальный код, для этого есть golf. Пишите понятный код, который и через год легко использовать.